# Explanation of this LINQ code which generates permutations

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

Can someone explain to me how this code works which generates permutations?

I see that it's using recursive list building but I can't quite get my brain around the exact mechanics.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    if (list.Count() == 1)
        return new List<IEnumerable<T>> { list };
    return list
        .Select((a, i1) => 
                    Permute(list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1))
                   .Select(b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b)))
        .SelectMany(c => c);
}
```

Comment: If you care about efficiency, don't bother on learning this code.

Comment: And, unless I'm reading too hastily, if you care about accuracy.  Permutations are by definition unordered, while Union, a set operation, both ignores order and eliminates duplicates.

Comment: mostly i care that i understand what the code does but now how it does it

Comment: Instead of list.Count() == 1, you can avoid over-enumerating the list with `list.Any() && !list.Skip(1).Any()`

Comment: "mostly i care that i understand what the code does but now how it does it" -- have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @phoog, you're totally right - i plug in the inputs (1, 2, 1) and it utterly fails - thanks!

Comment: @phoog: Did you mean that permutations are *ordered*? (Within each permutation, the order is vital - otherwise it looks like every other permutation!)

Comment: I also noticed this: `x.Select(y).SelectMany(c => c)` is equivalent to `x.SelectMany(y)`, so the return statement could be `return list.Select((a, i1) => Permute(list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1)).SelectMany(b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b)));`

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, of course.  *Permutations are, by definition, **ordered**.*  That was a second version of the comment.  Too much quick typing and I start using words that are supposed to be elsewhere in the sentence.

Comment: @phoog, even though it's not strictly a Q or an A, do you maybe want to put your optimized version in an edit to my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'd point out that this relies on the ordering of `Union`, which is unspecified, and only works if the values in the original collection are unique. Changing `Union` to `Concat` would fix that.

I suspect it's also frighteningly expensive. Anyway...

You can understand it by induction. It definitely works for a single element collection, based on the `if`. So, let's go from there.

Suppose we start with the assumption that it works for a collection of size `n` like this:

```
{ e1, ... en }
```

Now let's see whether it works for a collection of size `n + 1`. The call will bypass the "if", and go into the recursive return part. So we're left with:

```
list.Select((a, i1) => 
                Permute(list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1))
               .Select(b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b)))
    .SelectMany(c => c);
```

The `SelectMany` part just flattens a collection of collections - that's straightforward. So let's focus on the `Select` call. It's saying...

- For each element (`a`) in the original collection, which we know has index `i1`...

  - Work out the list *except* that element (that's the `list.Where(...)` part)
  - For each permutation of that smaller list (that's the `Permute` call)...
  - ... generate a new list consisting of element `a` followed by the "current permutation" (That's the `new List(...).Union(b)` part.)

So if our collection was { x, y, z } we'd get:

- Every collection of `{ y, z }` prefixed by `x`
- Every collection of `{ x, z }` prefixed by `y`
- Every collection of `{ x, y }` prefixed by `z`

That pretty much defines "every permutation"... so it works for `n + 1`.

Given the base case and the induction step, it therefore works for collections of any size greater than or equal to 1.